# Laptop automatically reboots after shutdown

Tags: windows-7, bios, shutdown

My laptop is a Dell N5110. These days the computer has a problem that after normally shutdown it automatic reboot in midnight. I have tried setting the power manager, system restore to prior time, setting system and security - "uncheck" to Auotomatically Restart. All these methods don't work. Now I try to disable Wake On Lan in BIOS, however, I could not find Wake On Lan in BIOS on  this computer.

Please help how to find Wake On Lan in BIOS on Dell Inspiron N5110 or resolve this problem any other useful ways.

Comment: Your notebook my not support WOL, many/most consumer-grade notebooks don't.

Comment: Have you checked your Scheduled Tasks to see if there's anything set to wake the computer to run a task at around midnight? Say, Windows Updates?

Comment: No schedule task that I have checked.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have any "fastboot" program installed? I solved a similar issue with a Dell laptop, but in that case it wasn't enable to normally start Windows after going to sleep... It works fine after removing that software.

Comment: There is no "fastboot" in this computer. But in one night, the computer did not reboot after I changed "window updates" Install Updates Automatically to Never Check Updates. Then I changed back to Check for Updates But Let Me Choose Whether to Download and Install Them in next day, the computer reboot again in the middle night.

Comment: Can you access BIOS and try to find POWER MANAGEMENTS SETUP - RESUME BY ALARM or something similar? Maybe you have a trigger for start de laptop everyday at midnight (usually it comes configured at 00:00).

Answer (score 1):

Try fix suggested in following link:

- [Fix for Windows 7 "random wake from sleep/Shutdown" problem](http://jack.ukleja.com/fix-for-windows-7-random-wake-from-sleep-problem/)

Also, Check whether these similar QAs helps:

- [Why does my computer keep switching on?](https://superuser.com/questions/46090/why-does-my-computer-keep-switching-on)
- [My computer reboots when I tell it to shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/62798/my-computer-reboots-when-i-tell-it-to-shutdown)
- [Why would my computer automatically restart after “shutdown” and “sleep”?](https://superuser.com/questions/202830/why-would-my-computer-automatically-restart-after-shutdown-and-sleep)
- [Laptop automatically reboots after shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/693818/laptop-automatically-reboots-after-shutdown)
- [My computer turned itself on. Was I hacked?](https://superuser.com/questions/420035/my-computer-turned-itself-on-was-i-hacked)

Comment: The first suggestion is over my knowledge. I can not do as it is too complicated. The others had been tried before I posted the question on this website. They are not working.