# Why my laptop with Windows turns on sometimes at night?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop

Why my laptop with Windows 7 turns on sometimes at night?
It turns off after few minutes.

Can anybody tell why does Windows 7 need to turn on the laptop?

Comment: Probably to install updates... check  your `Windows Updates` settings as it may be configured to wake the device at a certain time of night to install updates. This can often be 2am/3am

Comment: Check this - [Why does my computer keep switching on?](http://superuser.com/questions/46090/why-does-my-computer-keep-switching-on)

Answer (score 2):

Try to open a command prompt to run as administrator and type in PowerCFG - lastwake it might tell you what woke your computer or if you put in PowerCFG -waketimers it should tell you what is scheduled to wake your computer up.

Comment: It says `Type: Fixed Feature Power Button`. Do you know what does that mean?

Comment: I think that if it says power button.... maybe it means you have pressed the power button on the laptop or desktop to wake from sleep.. This is just an log entry in Event Viewer and not an error. You can check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your BIOS to see if you accidentally enable the alarm on auto start. If your BIOS support it.